# Will Chlorodifluoromethane (R22 refrigerant) react with calcium metal?

Tags: acid-base, halides, reactivity

I am attempting to recycle or find a use for chlorodifluoromethane, however I do not want to risk venting it into the atmosphere or exposing myself to hydrofluoric acid. Ideally, I would like to produce chlorine/fluorine salts for safe storage/disposal.

Edit: Upon further research, calcium fluoride appears to be a non-toxic salt of fluorine. MSDS warns that R22 will react with alkali metals as well as calcium, magnesium, etc. What conditions are required in the following reaction?

$$\ce{HCFCl2 + Ca -> CaF2 + ...}$$

Where all the fluorine is consumed by calcium. I am not concerned with other chloride salts since fluorine toxicity is my main concern.

Comment: Have you checked the Safety Data Sheet for it?

Comment: Yes, apparently it will react with Al, Zn, Mg, Ca, etc. and decompose at temperatures above 250C. Unfortunately, the details behind these reactions is unclear. I assume that F will attack an electron donor before Cl, but the potential to produce HF makes me not want to try this reaction.

Comment: I don't know where you are located, but I would consider giving it to an HVAC contractor. They usually don't charge as the refrigerant is rather valuable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the refrigerant in a 'non-refillable' vessel. In TX, they will only accept it if it is in a reclamation tank and if its of a certain purity, neither of which I can provide